# After remove App and reauthorize it, email permission is not asked again

Tags: facebook, email, authentication

I'm using FB.login with {scope:'email'} parameter.

When an user is logging in for the first time to my app, the login dialog ask him "if he authorize to connect to my app" and then ask him for "email permission". Well.

But if the user remove my app from his Facebook account, when he is logging in again to my app, the login dialog ask him for authorization but never ask him for email permission?! Is these permission always stored even the app is removed?

Thank you for answering and sorry for my English: I'm French :)